# Java - Strange directory problem?

Tags: java, file, debugging, file-io, directory

When I run a class with the following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    createDuplicateStructure("in", "out");
}

public static void createDuplicateStructure(String path_start, String path_result)
{
    File start = new File(path_start);
    File result = new File(path_result);
    duplicateDirectoryStructure(start, result);
}

public static void duplicateDirectoryStructure(File start_dir, File result_dir)
{
    //FileFilter used by listFiles(filter) - to make sure they are dirs
    FileFilter dirs_only = new FileFilter() 
            { 
                public boolean accept(File file){  return file.isDirectory();} 
            };
    File[] dir_contents = start_dir.listFiles(dirs_only);
    for(File dir : dir_contents)
    {
        File duplicate = new File(result_dir.getPath(), dir.getName());
        if(dir.mkdir())
        {
            duplicateDirectoryStructure(dir, duplicate);
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("ERROR: Unable to create dir! (" + duplicate.getPath() + ")");
        }
    }
}
```

I get this in the console:

```
 Error: Unable to create dir! (out/a)
 Error: Unable to create dir! (out/a)
 Error: Unable to create dir! (out/a)
```

The directory "out" is in the same directory as the .jar.
There is a directory "in" which contains "a", "b", and "c" directories (for testing).

Any ideas why this is not working?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the outcome if you instead of duplicate.getPath() print duplicate.getAbsolutePath()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should replace `dir.mkdir()` with `duplicate.mkdir()` because dir is the already existing source directory.

Comment: @guywhoneedsahand you need to accept the answer if it answers your question.

Comment: I know - I'm waiting for the timeout. "You can accept this question in x minutes".

Answer (score 3):

`dir.mkdir()` only returns true the directory was actually created. Try doing

```
if(dir.mkdir() || dir.exists())
```

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
`if(dir.mkdir())`
```

is trying to create the existing directory structure

if you change it to
    `if(duplicate.mkdir())`

you get another problem where it tries to create the a subdirectory under *out* which does not exist yet.

So change it to
    `if(duplicate.mkdirs())`

which will create the directory structure, or create the out directory before you start your loop.